# How to apply mixpanel on event 'triggering' of dropdown in antdesign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, antd, mixpanel

I am working on a react application where on the click of dropdown menu in Antdesign(when Menu opens), I have to apply mixpanel. Now the dropdown has a trigger props, which expects a string, "click". This could be a basic concept in javascript, but I am new to Javascript/react, so any help is appreciated.

While passing the props 'trigger' down to Dropdown, instead of writing

```
trigger="click"
```

I wrote a function returning "click" and having mixpanel functionality, but it won't work as trigger expects PropTypes.string while I am passing function(PropTypes.func).

```
<Dropdown
visible={visible}
onSelect={onSelect}
/* And other props */
// trigger="click"
trigger={handleTrigger}    I know this isn't correct, but I want 
                           somewhat this type of functionality
/>
```

The handleTrigger function is -

```
const handleTrigger=()=>{
// MixPanel event handling
return "click"
}
```

On writing above code doesn't give errors, but the dropdown functionality is not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: No, but a warning is generated, Failed prop type: Invalid prop `trigger` of type `function` supplied to `Dropdown`, expected `string`

Comment: May I know the reason why you want to pass a function instead of value 'click' directly?

Comment: As mentioned, I want to perform Mixpanel on this trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing down a function and not executing it, in order for that to work you should try to do it like this :

```
trigger={this.handleTrigger()}
```

this way you are passing down to the props the execution of the function and not the function itself